# "Within 7 working days upon arrival" vs. "of your arrival date"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, american-english, british-english, legalese

Two questions

1. Is there any difference between the sentence "within 7 working days upon arrival" and "within 7 working of your arrival date"?
2. How do we count these 7 working days? Do we include the arrival date or are they the 7 days after the date?

Comment: If it's a matter of legal significance, ask the person who requires you to abide by the terms. It's what *they* say that counts, not what people here think. But 7 working days will be at least 9 elapsed days (perhaps as much as a fortnight), so it's unlikely they'd disadvantage you for assuming "exclusive of start date" and/or "inclusive of upper limit" and consequently taking a day longer than stipulated.

Comment: The usual expression is "within X days **of**" a certain date.

Comment: I'd say "within seven days upon arrival" means after arrival, while "of arrival" could mean before or after depending on context. But dictionary definitions of "upon" don't really confirm that, so I can't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different phrases you can use to express this. I would say most commonly it's **within X days of** an event or **X  days from** an event:

> within 7 days of your arrival
>
> 10 days from your departure

Whether the day of your arrival or the day of your departure counts as a day is open to speculation and therefore at the discretion of the person who made the rule.